# What is equivalent in php of ASP Response.Expires=0

Tags: php, asp.net

I have this code in an ASP file:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
    Option Explicit
    Response.Expires = 0
%>
```

My question, what is the equivalent in PHP of the Response.Expires=0?

Thanks for the answers in advance.
Sz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to use your preferred search engine to find an answer :)

The "equivalent" in php would be session_cache_expire:

```
int session_cache_expire ([ string $new_cache_expire ] )
```

Here is the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response. You answer is my solution.